# iAd banners always fail, even in Apple's iAdSuite code

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, iad

Since yesterday, every time I try to work with iAd banners in my apps, all I get is the delegate method

```
bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:
```

and the error description is

> Error Domain=ADErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. Unknown error" UserInfo=0x756dfa0 {ADInternalErrorCode=0, ADInternalErrorDomain=ADErrorDomain, NSLocalizedFailureReason=Unknown error}.

This happens to me all the time and in all the projects I'm working in, even those that already had a version of iAd banners working, and even in a recent download of the iAdSuit Apple project. Neither on devices nor on Simulator. I also checked if there was any problem with my Wi-Fi connection, or 3G. Still not working with both.

I'm working with iOS 6.1 or below.

Does anyone know what is happening?